# NPOI for Excel file writing

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

I am using NPOI for writing some contents to a excel file.For some contents I have no issues in writing them to a cell but there are some contents like below

**"Continuous Arithmetic Operation in the statement Phi12Delta=xSt[2]-xSt[4]+360*ic_float(CntRotDifJ1J2);"**

I write this content in a cell using the below statement:

**oCell.SetCellValue(new XSSFRichTextString();**

there is no exception or error I am getting when the code runs. But when I try to opening the excel sheet to view the contents I am getting the error "Excel found unreachable code in the content of filename.xslx" and I am not able to open it. But the file size is increased( showing that some content in the file).

Answer (score 0):

which version are you using? Please try to use the latest version of NPOI: 2.0.6. Here is the download link: https://npoi.codeplex.com/releases/view/112932